# How to put Arraylist of Custom Object in a SharedPreference

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I want to save **Arraylist** of Custom type Object in **sharedPreference**. For that purpose I passed Arraylist to **Gson**, there is no compile error but after running this code device wait for long time and got stuck. Kindly suggest me other way if I am on wrong way.

```
public void storeApps(Context context, List<AppInfo> apps) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonData = gson.toJson(apps);// this line wait for long time at compile time.
    editor.putString(Fav, jsonData);
    editor.commit();
}
```

AppInfo Class

```
public class AppInfo {
    public String appname = "";
    public String pname = "";
    public String versionName = "";
    public int versionCode = 0;
    public Drawable icon;
    public int color = 0;

    public String getAppname() {
        return appname;
    }

    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public int getVersionCode() {
        return versionCode;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setAppname(String appname) {
        this.appname = appname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }

    public void setVersionCode(int versionCode) {
        this.versionCode = versionCode;
    }

    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public AppInfo() { }

    public AppInfo(String appname, String pname, String versionName, int versionCode, Drawable icon, int color) {
        this.appname = appname;
        this.pname = pname;
        this.versionName = versionName;
        this.versionCode = versionCode;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actualy app info is predefined class that is why the Gson is unable to convert it.You need to ceate your own class store the needed data only the field you want.

Comment: @Rohit Heera AppInfo is a class that i have created. It is not predefined class

Comment: Ok what is the size of the list

Comment: @RohitHeera apps.size() which is 29

Comment: I can post a code it works fine in my case when i can convert the contact list..

Comment: `this line wait for long time at compile time` what does that mean?

Comment: `Drawable icon;` is probably going to be a problem. You should not incude it in the serialization

Comment: @ njzk2 device stuck. I have upload AppInfo class as well.

Comment: How do you know that's the line where your app is stuck?

Comment: by debugging but there may any other error.

Comment: Won't `getClass().getClassLoader()` return an `AppInfo` classloader? Not a `Drawable`?

Comment: @cricket_007  I had implement Parcelable that's y i forget to remove this function. because there no need to implement Parcelable. Latest Upload AppInfo check it.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, my money is on the serialization of the drawable taking a long time.

Comment: @ cricket_007 I didn't got your point

Comment: Is it compulsory to implement Parcelable or Serialization at AppInfo Class??

Comment: Do you know how Gson works, or do you just expect it to work flawlessly? For each `AppInfo`, Gson needs to convert the `Drawable icon` to a string. The longest operation for building the JSON object it serializing the `Drawable` and will take longer for larger images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98855/discussion-between-tarikhelian-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mydata 

{

ArrayList<AppInfo> data;

    public Mydata (List<AppInfo> data) {

        this.data= data;

    }

    public List<AppInfo> getContactSyn() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setContactSyn(List<AppInfo> data) {
        this.data= data;
    }


}

 Gson gson = new Gson();
MyData datalist = new MyData(data);

    String jsonData = gson.toJson(datalist);
```

Comment: Actually you can covert list it is good practise to convert asingle object rather than a list of object

Comment: same problem again here

Comment: @njzk2 I think source is ok.

Comment: @Tarikhelian I am asking if Rohit has any source to support that claim [that converting a single object is "good practice"]

Comment: I have applied Rohit source as well but same result.

Comment: ok you can use drawable class can you convert this drawable to base 64 String thats whi it take lot of time to be convert.